# Cocos2d - animationwithframes:delay: deprecated

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, deprecated

I would like to know what I should use in place of

```
animationWithFrames:delay:
```

and

```
actionWithAnimation:restoreOriginalFrame:
```

since they give a warning that they've been deprecated.

Comment: check the CCDeprecated.h and .m files to learn how deprecated code should be written

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cocos2d 2.0 uses

CCAnimation

```
+(id) animationWithSpriteFrames:(NSArray*)frames delay:(float)delay
```

CCAnimate

```
+(id) actionWithAnimation: (CCAnimation*)anim
```

Docs:

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/2.0.0/interface_c_c_animation.html

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/2.0.0/interface_c_c_animate.html

Comment: Good answer, but it misses one detail of the OP's second half of the question. Specifically, you must also set the animation's `restoreOriginalFrame` property to match what was previously specified in the deprecated version. See Julio's answer below. (BTW, doc links are no longer working.)

Answer (score 11):

The only change you need to do is uses the new property: restoreOriginalFrame.

Remove restoreOriginalFrame from the constructor, then, in a new line, set the property:

```
animation.restoreOriginalFrame = NO;
```

That's it!

Comment: This is the right answer for the second half of the OP's question. Setting the animation's `restoreOriginalFrame` property to match what was previously specified is an important detail that the accepted answer misses.

Answer (score 0):

```
 CCAnimation *sampleAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithAnimationFrames: 
                                     sampleAnimFrames delayPerUnit:0.2f loops:7];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in my project i use.

```
CCSprite *image = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"a0001.png"];
        image.position = ccp(s.width/2,s.height/2);
        [self addChild:image];
        image.tag = 1;

        NSMutableArray *frames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            NSString *frameName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"a%04i.png",i];
            [frames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:frameName]];
        }
        CCAnimation *ani = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:frames delay:1.0f/8.0f];
        [image runAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:ani]];
```

This works fine for me.